# Python 3. Ошибка "TypeError"

Tags: python, строки, pycharm

```
element = -1
c = input()
nc = input()
while element != str:
   element = input()
   if (element % 2) == 0:
      c =+ 1
   elif (element % 2) == 1:
      nc =+ 1
print("Четных: " + c)
print("Нечетных: " + nc)
```

Пишет , что:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/feironox5/PycharmProjects/untitled1/hjh.py", line 6, in
>    if (element % 2) == 0: TypeError: not all arguments converted
>   during string formatting

Comment: В чём ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут все просто. Дело в том что `input` возвращает строку. В таком случае нужно использовать `int(input)`.Вот правильный код:

```
element = -1
c = int(input())
nc = int(input())
while element != str:
   element = int(input())
   if (element % 2) == 0:
      c =+ 1
   elif (element % 2) == 1:
      nc =+ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Не обладаю достаточной "репутацией", чтобы оставлять комментарии, так что пишу так.
Как уже было отвечено, type(c) == 'str' -> c += 1 (str + int), что неявно, плохо и не разрешено.

Пишу по другому поводу:

```
while element != str:
```

Введи в интерпретаторе python "str" (ничего добавлять не надо) и ты увидешь, что str - это класс. Выходит, что ты сравниваешь переменную типа int с классом str, что не имеет какого-либо смысла. Поэтому происходит бесконечный цикл. Постарайся запомнить ключевые слова python, чтобы не совершать таких ошибок.

Также хочу отметить, что переменные в python - это ссылки (указателей как в С нет), из-за чего ссылки можно переназначать. `str = 'text'` и ты больше не можешь использовать класс str, преобразование типов в str и т.д.